# surface of a torus by integration

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [surface area of torus of revolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83269/surface-area-of-torus-of-revolution)

> Let $R>r>0$ fixed. I want to compute the Area of $S=\operatorname{Im} \phi$ given by $$\phi(s,t):= \begin{pmatrix}(R+r\cos s )\cos t \\ (R+r\cos s) \sin t \\ r \sin s \end{pmatrix}$$

First I compute: $$D\phi = \begin{pmatrix}-r\sin(s)\cos t  & -R\sin(t) \\ -r\sin(s)\sin(t) & R\cos(t) \\ r\cos(s) & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

then the cross product of the first vertical row with the second vertical row is: $$\partial_{1}\phi \times \partial_{2} \phi = \begin{pmatrix} Rr\cos(s)\cos(t) \\ -Rr\sin(t)\cos(s)\\ -Rr\sin(s)\cos^{2}(t)-Rr\sin(s)\sin^{2}(t) \end{pmatrix},$$

so $$\left\|\partial_{1} \phi \times \partial_{2} \phi \right\| =\sqrt{R^{2}r^{2}(\cos^2 (s)(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2 (t))+\sin^2(s))} = Rr,$$

and that gives:$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} Rr \;ds \;dt = 4\pi^2 Rr$$

The results seems to be fine, but are my calculations fine, too? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that $4\pi^2Rr=(2\pi R)(2\pi r)$.  I always found this fascinating.